# JQuery dialog close is not working when using xhr

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a web page by using xhr aJax.

I received Jquery Dialog via xhr.responseText .

**A.jsp (Actually viewed page's getting data part)**

```
function getOrderData(tableid){
    if(xhrGetOr) {
        xhrGetOr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/Erpos/POS_orderAjaxGet.html?id="+tableid,true);
        xhrGetOr.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if(xhrGetOr.readyState == 4 && xhrGetOr.status == 200){
                var dialog = $(xhrGetOr.responseText).appendTo('body');
                viewdialog();
            }
        }
        xhrGetOr.send(null);
    }
}
```

When I click some button, getOrderData() is called and As all data is received, viewdialog() method is also called. So, dialog is displayed in a web page.

**POS_orderAjaxGet.jsp**

```
   <script>
           function viewdialog() {
                          $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                            closeOnEscape: false,

                            autoOpen: true,
                            resizable: false,
                            draggable: true,
                            move:false,
                            height:830,
                            width:1085,
                            modal: true,
                            position:[0,0]
                          });
                        }
          function closeMenu() {
                        alert("close event");  // this is well displayed
                        $( "#dialog" ).dialog("close");
                    }
    </script>

<body>
    <div id="dialog" title="order">
         <input id="ocancel"type="button" class="btn" value="close"       
          onclick="closeMenu();"> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Everything is good. but $( "#dialog" ).dialog("close") is not working. So I moved closeMenu() function to A.jsp. also not working...
pure POS_orderAjaGet's closeMenu() is very well wokring.
I think A.jsp can't find id 'dialog'

Let me know What problems is.

Comment: I would definitely keep the script tag that contains `viewdialog` and `closeMenu` in A.jsp, not in the returned dialog content. One of the benefits of AJAX is to make the page more performant; reducing the amount of content being sent over the wire.

Comment: That said, the structure of your code looks correct to me. As long as jQuery is properly loaded into the page, and you're not loading content into iframes or other tabs, it seems something else is going on. If you have a repro case in a fiddle or jsbin, you should post that.

Comment: Oh. When I examine page through chrome developer console, I make it. But I don't understand well. Anyway there are dialog div's parent div. So, I use document.getElementById("dialog").parentNode.remove();
It works like $("dialog").dialog("close").

Answer (score 0):

```
function closeMenu() {
    document.getElementById("dialog").parentNode.remove();
}
```

It same work. But I think that is not good solution.